# Target groups in ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

What is the use of target groups in ecs service.

Basically, how do targets in a target group communicate with the ecs tasks?

I explored the setup of my ecs service and target group to which it is pointed.
But the ip addresses of the ec2 instances are different. Then, how come does the traffic from load balancer reach my ecs tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Target Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) in AWS is a feature of Load Balancers. You configure load balancers to send traffic to Target Groups. The Target Group is only used in relation to Load Balancers. In your ECS Service you would configure it to register tasks with a Target Group, and you would have a Load Balancer send traffic to that Target Group.

If you are not using a Load Balancer, then you would not use a Target Group either.

Comment: But the target ip addresses are different than the ip address of the EC2 instance on which my tasks are running. Then, how come do they receive the traffic?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the `awsvpc` Network Mode for your ECS tasks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html If you use that mode, the tasks get their own private IP address, separate from the EC2 instance's IP address.

Comment: Yes, it's awsvpc network, but the ec2 instance ip address on which the task is running is different from the target ec2 instance ip address

Comment: The target IP address is the ECS task, **NOT** the EC2 instance. As I said in my last comment, when you use `awsvpc` networking mode for your ECS task, (a specific ECS task network setting I also linked to in my last comment) the ECS task gets its own Elastic Network Interface with its own IP address that is separate from the EC2 instance.

Comment: Okay, so basically we can let's say create a target group with target type as IP. And then, have our ecs service register targets within that target group for the ALB to route requests to? Is my understanding correct @Mark B?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it works.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your time! Have accepted your answer.